# optimizing manually-coded k-means in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization, k-means

So I'm writing a k-means script in MATLAB, since the native function doesn't seem to be very efficient, and it seems to be fully operational. It appears to work on the small training set that I'm using (which is a 150x2 matrix fed via text file). However, the runtime is taking exponentially longer for my target data set, which is a 3924x19 matrix.

I'm not the greatest at vectorization, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here's my k-means script so far (I know I'm going to have to adjust my convergence condition, since it's looking for an exact match, and I'll probably need more iterations for a dataset this large, but I want it to be able to finish in a reasonable time first, before I crank that number up):

```
clear all;

%take input file (manually specified by user
disp('Please type input filename (in working directory): ')
target_file = input('filename: ', 's');

%parse and load into matrix
data = load(target_file);

%prompt name of output file for later) UNCOMMENT BELOW TWO LINES LATER
% disp('Please type output filename (to be saved in working directory): ')
% output_name = input('filename:', 's')

%prompt number of clusters
disp('Please type desired number of clusters: ')
c = input ('number of clusters: ');

%specify type of kmeans algorithm ('regular' for regular, 'fuzzy' for fuzzy)
%UNCOMMENT BELOW TWO LINES LATER
% disp('Please specify type (regular or fuzzy):')
% runtype = input('type: ', 's')

%initialize cluster centroid locations within bounds given by data set

%initialize rangemax and rangemin row vectors
%with length same as number of dimensions
rangemax = zeros(1,size(data,2)); 
rangemin = zeros(1,size(data,2));

%map max and min values for bounds
for dim = 1:size(data,2)
    rangemax(dim) = max(data(:,dim));
    rangemin(dim) = min(data(:,dim));
end

% rangemax
% rangemin

%randomly initialize mu_k (center) locations in (k x n) matrix where k is
%cluster number and n is number of dimensions/coordinates

mu_k = zeros(c,size(data,2));

for k = 1:size(data,2)
    mu_k(k,:) = rangemin + (rangemax - rangemin).*rand(1,1);
end

mu_k

%iterate k-means

%initialize holding variable for distance comparison
comparisonmatrix = [];

%initialize assignment vector
assignment = zeros(size(data,1),1);

%initialize distance holding vector
dist = zeros(1,size(data,2));

%specify convergence threshold
%threshold = 0.001;

for iteration = 1:25

    %save current assignment values to check convergence condition
    hold_assignment = assignment;

    for point = 1:size(data,1)

        %calculate distances from point to centers
        for k = 1:c
            %holding variables
            comparisonmatrix = [data(point,:);mu_k(k,:)];

            dist(k) = pdist(comparisonmatrix);
        end

        %record location of mininum distance (location value will be between 1
        %and k)
        [minval, location] = min(dist);

        %assign cluster number (analogous to location value)
        assignment(point) = location;

    end

    %check convergence criteria

    if isequal(assignment,hold_assignment)
        break
    end

    %revise mu_k locations

    %count number of each label
    assignment_count = zeros(1,c);

    for i = 1:size(data,1)
        assignment_count(assignment(i)) = assignment_count(assignment(i)) + 1;
    end

    %compute centroids
    point_total = zeros(size(mu_k));

    for row = 1:size(data,1)
        point_total(assignment(row),:) = point_total(assignment(row)) + data(row,:);
    end

    %move mu_k values to centroids
    for center = 1:c
        mu_k(center,:) = point_total(center,:)/assignment_count(center);
    end
end
```

There are a lot of loops in there, so I feel that there's a lot of optimization to be made. However, I think I've just been staring at this code for far too long, so some fresh eyes could help. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything in the code block.

When the above code block is executed (in context) on the large dataset, it takes 3732.152 seconds, according to MATLAB's profiler, to make the full 25 iterations (I'm assuming it hasn't "converged" according to my criteria yet) for 150 clusters, but about 130 of them return NaNs (130 rows in mu_k).

Comment: There are plenty of culprits to which we can point, but you should really start your optimization by profiling.  `profile on; myScript; profile report; profile off;`  It's really easy and you will learn a lot.

Comment: I did do that...I think. I used the "Run and Time" button when executing, and the profiler report popped up after it finisher running. Here's a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/4rfq2ml) of what came up. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yup, that's it.  `pdist` is about 77% of your computation time, so you can only direct your efforts at "Self Time" component of `kmeans`.  Click on `kmeans` to see what lines are to blame.  It also can't hurt to see what `pdist` is doing (before it gets to `pdistmex`) and if there is any way to work around it.

Comment: I just noticed your loop is over number of points.  That's your problem -- vectorize this loop.

Comment: I did suspect that. That would be the longest loop in the iterative process.

I'm not really sure how to interpret the profiler output when it comes to pdist and pdistmex; it does look like pdistmex is where the  most time is spent, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Profiling will help, but the place to rework your code is to avoid the loop over the number of data points (`for point = 1:size(data,1)`).  Vectorize that.

In your `for iteration` loop here is a quick partial example,

```
[nPoints,nDims] = size(data);

% Calculate all high-dimensional distances at once
kdiffs = bsxfun(@minus,data,permute(mu_k,[3 2 1])); % NxDx1 - 1xDxK => NxDxK
distances = sum(kdiffs.^2,2); % no need to do sqrt
distances = squeeze(distances); % Nx1xK => NxK

% Find closest cluster center for each point
[~,ik] = min(distances,[],2); % Nx1

% Calculate the new cluster centers (mean the data)
mu_k_new = zeros(c,nDims);
for i=1:c,
    indk = ik==i;
    clustersizes(i) = nnz(indk);
    mu_k_new(i,:) = mean(data(indk,:))';
end
```

This isn't the only (or the best) way to do it, but it should be a decent example.

Some other comments:

1. Instead of using `input`, make this script into a function to efficiently handle input arguments.
2. If you want an easy way to specify a file, see `uigetfile`.
3. With many MATLAB functions, such as `max`, `min`, `sum`, `mean`, etc., you can specify a dimension over which the function should operate.  This way you an run it on a matrix and compute values for multiple conditions/dimensions at the same time.
4. Once you get decent performance, consider iterating longer, specifically until the centers no longer change or the number of samples that change clusters becomes small.
5. The cluster with the smallest distance for each point, `ik`, will be the same with squared Euclidean distance.

Comment: There's a lot happening there, though. I apologize for requesting some handholding, but vectorization seems to be rather hit-or-miss for me. How could I reform that section to avoid the loop?

Comment: Updated with example. Just fixed `mu_k_new` too.

Comment: Oh, so this example not only removes the point for loop, but it also does a bunch of other stuff, too.

Could you explain what indk = ik==i does? I've never seen a formulation like that before.

Indeed, when I can get better runtime, I'll be iterating on the order of hundreds or so.

Comment: `ik==i` tests each value of `ik` for equality to `i` and returns a `logical` array the same size as `ik`.

Comment: Oh, okay. Do you have an eyeball on how much adapting the above snippet to my code would reduce the runtime? Currently, according to the profiler, pdist is being called almost a million and a half times, over 2870.624 seconds.

Comment: Dunno... two orders of magnitude probably!  ;)

Comment: Awesome! It'll go from an hour down to mere minutes, if that. I've marked your answer (not enough reputation to upvote yet :( ), not that there are other options for answers... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to ask...why is there no need to calculate square roots? Isn't that part of the Euclidean distance calculation?