# Improve performance of nested loops MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization, nested-loops

I am trying to analyse a lot of data which is making my program run painfully slow.
I am reading in a dataset from a .txt file to a cell array.
I am using a cell array as in order to classify my data, which is in the form of two attributes, I need the classes which are chars.

I want to find the resubstitution error using a nearest mean classifier.
I have a main outer loop which loops through each line of my dataset (tens of thousands). Each line is removed in turn, one on each iteration. The mean of two attributes is re calculated on each iteration with the line removed. The main hang point seems to be the next section where I want to calculate for each line in my dataset:

- The Euclidian distance between the data on that line (2 attribute values) and
  the mean of each of my classes.
- I then want to record the class whose mean the attributes mean value is closest to, this will be its assigned class.
- Finally i want to check whether this assigned class is the correct
  class.

Currently this loop looks like this.

```
errorCount = 0;
for l = 1:20000
    closest = 100;
    class = 0;
    attribute1 = d{2}(l);
    attribute2 = d{3}(l);
    for m = 1:numel(classes)
        dist = sqrt((attribute1-meansattr1(m))*(attribute1-meansattr1(m)) + (attribute2-meansattr2(m))*(attribute2-meansattr2(m)));
        if dist < closest
            closest = dist;
            class = m;
        end
    end

    if strcmp(d{1}(l),classes(class))
        %correct
    else
        errorCount = errorCount + 1;
    end
end
```

`d` is my cell array where `d{2}` is a column holding my attribute 1 values. I access these values with `d{1}(1)` for the first row in that column.

`classes` are the unique classes from my dataset, so for each of my classes I calculate the Euclidean distance to it.

`meansattr1` and `meansattr2` are arrays containing the mean values for each of my attributes. These are updated on each iteration of the outer loop when a line is removed.

Hopefully that helps you understand the code that I have. Any help in optimising and speeding up these calculations is much appreciated.

Comment: The easiest speed improvement is to remove the `sqrt` call.  Finding the closest distance squared is exactly the same as the closest distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially optimizing the iterated part of the k-means algorithm, so you can reference [my previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165505/2778484) for a method of vectorizing this.  However, here is how you would do it for your problem and data format.

Take a random data set like the following,

```
numClasses = 5;
numPoints = 20e3;
numDims = 2;

classes = strsplit(num2str(1:numClasses));

% generate random data (expected error rate of (numClasses-1)/numClasses)
d{1} = classes(randi(numClasses,numPoints,1));
d{2} = rand(numPoints,1);
d{3} = rand(numPoints,1);

% random initial class centers
meansattr1 = rand(5,1);
meansattr2 = rand(5,1);
```

Your code, compacted and storing each point's closest class ID and the distance to that class becomes:

```
closestDistance = zeros(numPoints,1);  nearestCluster = zeros(numPoints,1);
errorCount = 0;
for l = 1:numPoints
    closest = 100; iclass = 0;
    attribute1 = d{2}(l); attribute2 = d{3}(l);

    for m = 1:numel(classes)
        dist = sqrt((attribute1-meansattr1(m))*(attribute1-meansattr1(m)) + ...
            (attribute2-meansattr2(m))*(attribute2-meansattr2(m)));
        if dist < closest
            closest = dist; closestDistance(l) = closest;
            iclass = m; nearestCluster(l) = iclass;
        end
    end

    if ~strcmp(d{1}(l),classes(iclass))
        errorCount = errorCount + 1;
    end
end
```

The vectorized version of the above is then:

```
data = [d{2}(:) d{3}(:)];
meansattr = [meansattr1(:) meansattr2(:)];

kdiffs = bsxfun(@minus,data,permute(meansattr,[3 2 1]));

allDistances = sqrt(sum(kdiffs.^2,2)); % no need to do sqrt
allDistances = squeeze(allDistances); % Nx1xK => NxK

[closestDistance,nearestCluster] = min(allDistances,[],2); % Nx1

correctClassIds = str2num(char(d{1}(:)));
errorCount = nnz(nearestCluster ~= correctClassIds);
```

The results in `errorCount`, `closestDistance` and `nearestCluster` are equivalent to the previous solution.  You can remove the sqrt and get the same results in `errorCount` and `nearestCluster`, as the code comment indicates.

Say you want to do the next step of updating `meansattr1` and `meansattr2`:

```
% Calculate the NEW cluster centers (mean the data)
meansattr_new = zeros(numClasses,numDims);
clustersizes = zeros(numClasses,1);
for ii=1:numClasses,
    indk = nearestCluster==ii;
    clustersizes(ii) = nnz(indk);
    meansattr_new(ii,:) = mean(data(indk,:))';
end

meansattr1_next = meansattr_new(:,1);
meansattr2_next = meansattr_new(:,2);
```

Put this all in a `while errorCount>THRESH` or `for jj = 1:MAXITER`, and you should have what you are after.

Comment: Thank you, there is a definite performance increase from doing it this way. I will have to look at other aspects of my program to see where i can do similar enhancements.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest speed improvement is to remove the `sqrt` call. Finding the closest distance squared is exactly the same as the closest distance.

Next, you can vectorise the inner loop.  It's been so long since I did any MatLab so I might get the following code wrong, but the idea is to make those two attributes into a vector of length `numel(classes)`.  Then you can compute the differences directly and square them.

Something like this:

```
d1 = attribute1 - meansattr1;
d2 = attribute2 - meansattr2;
[closest, class] = min( d1 .* d1 + d2 .* d2 );
```

By the way, it's not a great idea to use `class` as a variable (if you even can).  It's a reserved word.

Comment: 'closest=strt(closest)' is missing in case the distance is used, the variable contains the squared distance.

Comment: Sure, but the original code doesn't show where that's used either.  It's easy to take the `sqrt` *after* all the looping.

Answer (score 0):

I started with the solution of paddy, simple replacing of variable names:

```
[closest, cl] = min( (d{2}(m) - meansattr1).^2 +(d{3}(m) - meansattr2).^
2);
```

Thus we have a single line for-loop, common strategy: make a function of it and put it into arrayfun:

```
f=@(x)min( (d{2}(x) - meansattr1).^2 +(d{3}(x) - meansattr2).^2)
[sqclosest,cl]=arrayfun(f,1:numel(d{2}));

%If necessary real distances could be calculated:
%closest=sqrt(sqclosest)

errorCount=sum(arrayfun(@(x,c)(1-strcmp(x,classes(c))),d{1},cl))
```

Note: Do not use "class" or any other reserved word for other purposes.