# Is it possible to vectorize code which operates on submatrices along the same dimension in two matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I apologize for the verbose title. 
Please consider the following code, which might come up in `k-means` clustering.

```
rng(1)
num_samples = 10;
samples = randi(100, num_samples, 3);
cluster_centroids = randi(16,3);
cluster_indices = zeros(num_samples,1);

for index = 1:num_samples
    distances = sqrt(sum((samples(index) - cluster_centroids).^2, 2));
    cluster = find(distances == min(distances), 1)
    cluster_indices(index) = cluster;
end
```

Is there some way to vectorize it and remove the for loop, so that we are effectively handling all the samples (which are tuples of three integers) together?

Comment: Before vectorizing, that code doesn't even seem to return sensible output. Should `cluster_indices = zeros(num_samples);` be `cluster_indices = zeros(num_samples,1);`?

Comment: Yes, it should. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your existing code, which I listed at the bottom, but first the vectorized answer.  The core of the answer is similar to [my past solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165505/2778484).  I've modified it slightly to your variables, and added some more explanation:

```
[nPoints,nDims] = size(samples);
k = 3; % ? size(cluster_centroids,1)

% Calculate all high-dimensional distances at once
% (NxDx1 - 1xDxK => NxDxK)
kdiffs = bsxfun(@minus,samples,permute(cluster_centroids,[3 2 1]));
distances = sum(kdiffs.^2,2); % no need to do sqrt
distances = squeeze(distances); % Nx1xK => NxK
```

The `distances` are the important values to vectorize.  The rest is fairly trivial:

```
% Find closest cluster center for each point
[~,cluster_indices] = min(distances,[],2); % Nx1
```

Then you will need to update the cluster centers for the following iterations:

```
cluster_centroids_new = zeros(k,nDims);
for i=1:k,
    indk = cluster_indices==i;
    clustersizes(i) = nnz(indk);
    cluster_centroids_new(i,:) = mean(samples(indk,:))';
end
```

To add a little discussion to this code, note that `cluster_centroids_new` has a row for each cluster, but if a cluster has no members, then that row will be `NaN`s.

Issues with code in question:

1. `cluster_indices` is initialized as a matrix instead of a vector. Fix: `cluster_indices = zeros(num_samples,1);` (as mentioned by horchler).
2. You are not indexing `samples` properly in the `distances` computation. Change `samples(index)` to `samples(index,:)` to extract a sample.
3. The distance between each N-D sample and `cluster_centroids` needs to be `sum((repmat(samples(index,:),size(cluster_centroids,1),1) - cluster_centroids).^2, 2)` to compute distance of a sample to all `k=size(cluster_centroids,1)` clusters.
4. Not definitely an error, but be sure you mean `cluster_centroids = randi(16,3);` which gives a 3x3 matrix with numbers from 1 to 16.